# SQL query returning blank results

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the query below, it returns no data! Does anyone know why that may be?

```
select 
    es.SubCategoryName,
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductSID,
    CAST (ps.Date as date) as Date,
    Price as Price, 
    Cost as Cost 
from 
    ProductStatus as ps
join 
    v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ps.ProductSID
join 
    PriceZone as pz on pz.PriceZoneID = ps.PriceZoneID
where
    es.ProductSID = '9577C393-833B-4ACB-9A8E-8B748C65A488'
    and ps.Date = '2014-12-17' 
group by
    es.SubCategoryName,
    es.ClientProductID, es.ProductSID,
    ps.Date, ps.Price, ps.Cost
```

I know if you forget to put inverted commas around a date, you get blank results.

But I'm not sure why it would happen here?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

TIA.

Comment: You'll need to add the data in order to get a good answer

Comment: Why are you casting your date as a date in the select clause but not the where clause?

Comment: convert your string in to date

Comment: What's the point of using `GROUP BY` if you don't have any aggregation????

Comment: Jonathan, Joe, Ajay and Eric. Thank you all for responding to the post. I can't share the data, as it's confidential, but I was able to resolve the issue internally. The casting of the date was done from a previous example a colleague provided and it worked in that instance. But the issue here was with the Product Status table. Thank you all for responding quickly!

Answer (score 1):

You should try casting your date column to date in the `WHERE` statement. If it is stored as a `datetime` it won't end up matching.

```
 SELECT 
 es.SubCategoryName    AS SubCategoryName
,es.ClientProductID    AS ClientProductID 
,es.ProductSID         AS ProductSID
,CAST(ps.DATE AS DATE) AS DATE
,Price                 AS Price
,Cost                  AS Cost
FROM 
           ProductStatus         AS ps
INNER JOIN v_EnterpriseStructure AS es ON es.ProductSID  = ps.ProductSID
INNER JOIN PriceZone             AS pz ON pz.PriceZoneID = ps.PriceZoneID
WHERE 
    es.ProductSID         = '9577C393-833B-4ACB-9A8E-8B748C65A488'
AND CAST(ps.DATE AS DATE) = CAST('2014-12-17' AS date)

GROUP BY es.SubCategoryName
,es.ClientProductID
,es.ProductSID
,ps.DATE
,ps.Price
,ps.Cost;
```

I would give this a try. I am guessing it has to do with the type of columns sql is storing the data as.

Comment: Might I also recommend using a sql code formatting tool like www.poorsql.com . As you can see in my answer I also lined up the `AS` statements and my `=` operators. I personally believe this will make your code more readable. Keeping your SQL readable is a kind thing to do to yourself when you look back at this code or someone who may inherit your code.

Comment: Your formatting is very unreadable to me and I'd personally change it to something that didn't require a formatting tool tbh

Comment: @JoePhillips different strokes for different folks. I am always open to new ideas though, how would you format your sql? to increase readablity?

Comment: It's totally preference but I would prefer this: https://gist.github.com/phillijw/8b2683cefe01931107486735af393d21
(1) It's easy to edit by hand
(2) Pretty easy to read and fairly standard

Everyone is different though :)

Answer (score 0):

That would happen because `2014-12-17` evaluates to 1985.  This is an integer, not a date.

Presumably, no dates match 1985.  SQL Server will attempt to convert that value to a date, which is something like '1905-09-06'.

Comment: I have a feeling its a string not an int

Comment: @JoePhillips . . . A string would generate an error if the single quotes were dropped.

Comment: What makes you believe the single quotes were dropped?

Comment: @JoePhillips . . . That is how I interpret what the OP is asking:  "I know if you forget to put inverted commas around a date . . .".

Answer (score 0):

You added `CAST (ps.Date as date)` into your Select statement, it would probably be prudent to use a similar format in your where "date" clause, but you should really post some of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any information about your table, I am going to assume that the Data Type of the ProductStatus.Date column is 'datetime.' So I believe that your issue is in your WHERE clause. Try changing to this:

```
WHERE 
        es.ProductSID = '9577C393-833B-4ACB-9A8E-8B748C65A488'
        and year(ps.Date) = '2014' and month(ps.Date) = '12' and day(ps.Date) = '17'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Darth, apologies for the delay in responding. The data I have is confidential, so I can't re-post it. However, when I spoke to a colleague about this issue, they said it was because the product status table didn't have the latest data! The issue is now resolved. But thank you for the prompt response to the query!